# XAML Trigger WPF Tab selection changes more than the tab header

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I have a trigger that when a tab is selected I color the tab blue and the text white, but the problem is that this trigger, for some reason, also changes the text color in the tabheader body to white as well in the group boxes. It seems that anything that has a header turns to white.

How do I make it so only the header in the tab itself

```
<TabItem Header="Query Editor" <-- This text only
```

will change to white when selected and no other text on the form?

Below is the code I am using.

Thanks.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border"
                        Background="WhiteSmoke"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                        CornerRadius="6,6,0,0">

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            ContentSource="Header"
                            Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#00396a" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

may be TabItem.HeaderTemplate will work for you.

```
        <TabControl>
            <TabControl.Resources>
                 <DataTemplate x:Key="headerText">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="content" Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="content" Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource headerText}" />
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>



            <TabItem Header="fsdf" >
                <TextBlock Text="lkajsldkjaskl" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="ghj">
                <TextBlock Text="ghj" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="fs556df">
                <TextBlock Text="jjj" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

you could have 2headerstyle, one normal one selected. in your tabitem style triggers you can set the headertemplate to the right "IsSelected" one.

Comment: Says it cant find HeaderTemplate.  any other ideas?

Comment: While this is nice, it does not answer the question.  I need to have the tab change color and only the font color of the tab and the tab alone be white when selected. The roll over is a nice touch, but it still doesn't solve the problem of the text in the group boxes also being affected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution!

Thank you all for your help.

What I changed was I removed the ContentPresenter and replaced it with the textblock that only affected the tab header itself.

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="4" Color="GhostWhite"/>
                 </LinearGradientBrush>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
     </Style>

     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                     <Grid>
                         <Border Name="Border"
                             Background="WhiteSmoke"
                             BorderBrush="Black"
                             BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                             CornerRadius="6,6,0,0">

                             <TextBlock 
                                 x:Name="TabItemContent" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                 Margin="12,2,12,2" />
                         </Border>
                     </Grid>
                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                         <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                             <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#00396a" />
                             <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="TabItemContent" Value="White"/>
                         </Trigger>
                         <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```